# Get username of person using Facebook PHP SDK 4.4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking through graphalbum and I can't find a place to get their username.

How can I grab someones username using the facebook api?

I was able to do this using the old API by doing a simple

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
$user_profile['username'];
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2014 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * You are hereby granted a non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free license to
 * use, copy, modify, and distribute this software in source code or binary
 * form for use in connection with the web services and APIs provided by
 * Facebook.
 *
 * As with any software that integrates with the Facebook platform, your use
 * of this software is subject to the Facebook Developer Principles and
 * Policies [http://developers.facebook.com/policy/]. This copyright notice
 * shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
 * THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
 * FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
 * DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
 *
 */
namespace Facebook;

/**
 * Class GraphAlbum
 * @package Facebook
 * @author Daniele Grosso <daniele.grosso@gmail.com>
 */

class GraphAlbum extends GraphObject
{
    /**
     * Returns the ID for the album.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('id');
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the viewer can upload photos to this album.
     *
     * @return boolean|null
     */
    public function canUpload()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('can_upload');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of photos in this album.
     *
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getCount()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('count');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the ID of the album's cover photo.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCoverPhoto()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('cover_photo');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the time the album was initially created.
     *
     * @return \DateTime|null
     */
    public function getCreatedTime()
    {
        $value = $this->getProperty('created_time');
        if ($value) {
            return new \DateTime($value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the time the album was updated.
     *
     * @return \DateTime|null
     */
    public function getUpdatedTime()
    {
        $value = $this->getProperty('updated_time');
        if ($value) {
            return new \DateTime($value);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the description of the album.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('description');
    }

    /**
     * Returns profile that created the album.
     *
     * @return GraphUser|null
     */
    public function getFrom()
    {
      return  $this->getProperty('from', GraphUser::className());
    }

    /**
     * Returns a link to this album on Facebook.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getLink()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('link');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the textual location of the album.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('location');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the title of the album.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('name');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the privacy settings for the album.
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getPrivacy()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('privacy');
    }

    /**
     * Returns the type of the album. enum{profile, mobile, wall, normal, album}
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->getProperty('type');
    }

    //TODO: public function getPlace() that should return GraphPage
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As being talked in the comments, this answer is only valid with apps created before the end of April 2014 and will be obsolete after April 2015.*

Without using the PHP SDK, you can still [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) the username from the following HTTP request:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[USER_ID]
```

The result will be:

```
{
   "id": [USER_ID],
   "first_name": "",
   "gender": "male",
   "last_name": "",
   "link": "https://www.facebook.com/[USERNAME]",
   "locale": "en_US",
   "name": "",
   "username": [USERNAME]
}
```

No access token needed.

Comment: that´s not correct, you only get app scoped id of a user with v2.0 and the username is not included in the json result. this would only work with the global/real id and you don´t get that one either.

Comment: that´s with your global/real id. please read my comment again, i´ve added a sentence to make it perfectly clear ;)

Comment: However  `graph.facebook.com/me` gives my global ID, as well as `me/?fields=friends`.

Comment: then you are most likely using a v1.0 app.

Comment: I am using the Graph API Explorer with v2.2.

Comment: select another app (a "real" one) in the api explorer. of course you get your global id in the api explorer, because if you got a global id once it will not change to an app scoped id.

Comment: also, check out the friends you get with /me/friends. those are most likely only friends who authorized the api explorer app too ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You are right, this answer is valid only with v1 apps. Still helpful in some cases in my opinion.

Comment: exactly, and since you would need to use an app created before end of april 2014, and since it would be void after april 2015, we can pretty much forget about v1 stuff already :) - may be a good idea to include information in your answer that it will only work with an old app and will stop working soon.

Answer (score 2):

Since v2.0 of the Graph API, the username is not available anymore:

> /me/username is no longer available.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog